# Distributed computing framework for Clojure/Java

Tags: java, clojure, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I'm developing an application where I need to distribute a set of tasks across a potentially quite large cluster of different machines.

Ideally I'd like a very simple, idiomatic way to do this in Clojure, e.g. something like:

```
; create a clustered set of machines
(def my-cluster (new-cluster list-of-ip-addresses))

; define a task to be executed
(deftask my-task (my-function arg1 arg2))

; run a task 10000 times on the cluster
(def my-job (run-task my-cluster my-task {:repeat 10000})

; do something with the results:
(some-function (get-results my-job))
```

Bonus if it can do something like Map-Reduce on the cluster as well.....

What's the best way to achieve something like this? Maybe I could wrap an appropriate Java library?

UPDATE:

Thanks for all the suggestion of Apache Hadoop - looks like it might fit the bill, however it seem a bit like overkill since I'm not needing a distributed data storage system like Hadoop uses (i.e. i don't need to process billions of records)... something more lightweight and focused on compute tasks only would be preferable if it exists.

Comment: in the clojure google group, there have been discussions about terracotta, GridGain and the java (JMS, JXTA/shoal, JINI ) standards, you can google for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hadoop is the base for almost all the large scale *big data* excitement in the Clojure world these days though there are better ways than using Hadoop directly.

[Cascalog](https://github.com/nathanmarz/cascalog) is a very popular front end:

```
    Cascalog is a tool for processing data on Hadoop with Clojure in a concise and
    expressive manner. Cascalog combines two cutting edge technologies in Clojure 
    and Hadoop and resurrects an old one in Datalog. Cascalog is high performance, 
    flexible, and robust.
```

Also check out Amit Rathor's [swarmiji](https://github.com/amitrathore/swarmiji) distributed worker framework build on top of RabbitMQ. it's less focused on data processing and more on distributing a fixed number of tasks to a pool of available computing power. (P.S. It's in his book, [Clojure in Action](http://www.manning.com/rathore/))

Comment: thanks, look very interesting. although I'm more interested in distributed processing rather than big data - hadoop seems more focussed on the latter?

Comment: In my experience Hadoop is quite awkward; it's a lot of work to set up a cluster, and it's tricky to debug. If you don't need HDFS, it's much simpler just to use a queueing system like RabbitMQ to ship around s-expressions. There are a few libraries existing to do this, but wrapping the Java RabbitMQ client in a couple pages of Clojure code is easy enough to be in "left as an exercise for the reader" territory.

Answer (score 7):

Although I haven't gotten to use it yet, I think that [Storm](https://storm.apache.org/) is something that you might find useful to explore:

> Storm is a distributed realtime computation system. Similar to how Hadoop provides a set of general primitives for doing batch processing, Storm provides a set of general primitives for doing realtime computation. Storm is simple, can be used with any programming language, and is a lot of fun to use!

Answer (score 4):

Hadoop is exacly what you need: [Apache Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/)

Answer (score 3):

[Storm](https://storm.apache.org/) might suit your needs better than Hadoop, as it has no distributed data storage and has low latency. It's possible to split up and process data, similar to MapReduce, the [Trident](https://storm.apache.org/releases/current/Trident-tutorial.html) api makes this very simple.

It is partly written in Clojure, so I suppose Clojure interop is easier.

Another option is [Onyx](http://www.onyxplatform.org/) which offers similar functionality, but is a pure Clojure based project.